# Is it possible to create a machine image from an Ubuntu1804 VMDK in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-18.04

This is a really simple question really aimed at the Google Cloud support folks.  I'm on the free trial at the moment, so don't have paid support and hence using the community forum.

Is it possible to create a machine image from an Ubuntu 1804 VMDK?

The instructions I have been following here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks
list Ubuntu 1804 as one of the supported operating systems.  However, when I go to the "Create an image" page, only 1404 and 1604 are listed as options.

I have also tried taking the equivalent command line and modifying the --os=ubuntu-1604 to --os=ubuntu-1804, but this resulted in:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.import) argument --os: Invalid choice: 'ubuntu-1804'. Did you mean 'ubuntu-1604'?
```

So, is it just that the original link is incorrect in listing 1804 as a supported OS? or is there some code that needs to be updated to add it to the list of options? Or ...

I did run the precheck tool in the OS and that did give me:

```
########################################
# SHA2 Driver Signing Check -- SKIPPED #
########################################
  * INFO: Only applicable on Windows 2008 systems.
##############################
# OS Version Check -- FAILED #
##############################
  * INFO: OSInfo: &{LongName:Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS ShortName:ubuntu Version:18.04 Kernel:5.0.0-37-generic Architecture:x86_64}
  * FATAL: version: "18.04" not supported
###############################
# Powershell Check -- SKIPPED #
###############################
  * INFO: Not applicable on non-Windows systems.
#########################
# Disks Check -- PASSED #
#########################
  * INFO: `lsblk -i` results:
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT ...
```

So it would seem that 1804 is not supported.  If this is the case is there a timeline for it being supported ?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Stackoverflow is the wrong place for this question. Google Cloud has a feature request and issue tracker page. Post your question there: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley and Jujosiga - I have now transferred the request to the Google issue trackers - I read something that suggested help should be sought through SO.  Here is the link to the issue I created https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147770481

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is something wrong with google documentation, looking into the link you shared, in [compatibility tool](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks#precheck) section, there is a [compatibility issue](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/compute-image-tools/image-import.html#compatibility-and-known-limitations) github link where they mention the last supported Ubuntu Image is 16.04, could be a good idea to create a [Public issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) with Google about this.

There are two things you can try to create your VM Instance with Ubuntu 18.04.X:

- Use [Velostrata](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.8/) to migrate your entire VMware machine to GCP.
- Create a VM Instance from scratch with [Google Drawfork Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#shielded-images) image.

Hope this information helps!